# Calculate modulo of permutations of repeated integers

Tags: algorithm, modular-arithmetic

I'd like to calculate **P<sub>s</sub> `mod` K** where **P<sub>s</sub>** is the total number of unique permutations of elements in a set **S**. The problem is, the set **S** can have repetitions, so **P<sub>s</sub> = n! / (f<sub>1</sub>!f<sub>2</sub>! ... f<sub>n</sub>!)**, where **n** is the number of elements, and denominator the product of factorial of frequencies of each element in **S**.

The integer **n** can be assumed significantly large, say around `10^6`, and wouldn't likely fit in a `uint64_t`. Is it even possible to calculate **P<sub>s</sub> `mod` K** without resorting to an arbitrary precision library? If yes, are there any fast methods to calculate it?

Comment: 10^6 fits in a `uint64_t` by the way.

Comment: Or did you mean that `n!` wouldn't fit in a `uint64_t`?

Comment: Yep, `n!` doesn't fit in.

Comment: btw. if n is around `10^6!` then **Ps** `mod` **K** is in most cases going to be 0 unless K is extremely large.

Comment: I assume that `k` is not necessarily prime either?

Comment: Yes it is. I was solving a programming problem which forced me into this. The problem specifies `K = 10^9+7`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider as an example `9!/(4!3!2!)`. This is

```
9.8.7.6   5.4.3   2.1
------- x ----- x ---
4.3.2.1   3.2.1   2.1
```

In other words it is a product of 3 binomial coefficients `9C4 x 5C3 x 2C2`. In this way you are always going to be able to reduce it to a product of binomial coefficients. You need to work out these binomial coefficients modulo `K` and multiply the answers together modulo `K`.

So you need an efficient way to work out binomial coefficients modulo `K`.

I don't know how feasible this is for `n == 10^6` but a method for efficiently calculating binomial coefficients mod `K` is given here:

https://fishi.devtail.io/weblog/2015/06/25/computing-large-binomial-coefficients-modulo-prime-non-prime/

Comment: That's a neat observation! I'm going to get reading that article. I'll get back as soon as I have a working implementation.

Comment: @MethusaelMurmu Good luck. I think it's going to be quite hard - I'd do a detailed search to see if a library does this already.

Comment: The blog link got updated: https://fishi.devtail.io/weblog/2015/06/25/computing-large-binomial-coefficients-modulo-prime-non-prime/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate e.g. **n!modK**, you don't need to calculate **n!** first. Instead you could do a loop that looks like this.

```
result = 1
for(i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
  result = (result * i) % K
}
```

The easiest way to explain why this works is to look at what happens to the last digit of a number when you multiply it with something else.
e.g. 1234 * 3. What is the last digit of the result? It's a 2 which is equal to (4*3)mod10. The last digit of the result is only affected by the last digit of the two factors. That is true in every number system. Not just base 10. Therefore it's sufficient for the variable **result** to store the last digit of the result in base **K**.

Comment: The problem is that the question involves division. If you know what `n!`, `r!` and `(n - r)!` are modulo `K`, that doesn't tell you the value of `n!/(r! * (n - r)!)` modulo `K` because the denominator might not be an invertible element of the ring of integers modulo `K`.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a need to calculate **P<sub>s</sub> `mod` K** for many values of **P<sub>s</sub>**, then it might be wise to precompute **n! `mod` K** for all values of **n** that you might need (if **n** ≤ 10<sup>6</sup> then that's reasonable).

Also, if **K** is prime, you can handle division by instead multiplying by the "[modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)" of the number you want to divide by. For instance, if **K**=1,000,000,007 then instead of dividing by 2 you can multiply by 500,000,004.

There are a few ways to compute it, the easiest one being to calculate **x<sup>K-2</sup> `mod` K** (this works thanks to [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)). You can then precalculate the modular multiplicative inverse of every factorial as well. Then it's very easy to calculate **P<sub>s</sub> `mod` K** using the cached values.